# Using not equal or missing in SOLR query

Tags: solr

Looking for a way to convert following expression to solr query.

`ISNULL(field) OR field != 1`

I have tried several things,

`-field:1 OR -field:*`

`-(-field:1 AND field:*)`

`(-field:1 OR (*:* -field:*))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr Standard Query Parser does not support searching a field for empty/null value. In this situation the filter needs to be negated (exluding documents having any value in the field) so that the query remains valid.

However, using a [range query](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/the-standard-query-parser.html#TheStandardQueryParser-RangeSearches) is preferred to prevent inconsitent behaviors when using wildcard within negative subqueries.

So `ISNULL(field)` becomes `-field:[* TO *]`

Also, when applying a filter and a negated filter in the same fq param, you need to add `*:*` on the latter and ensure the first `-` operator applies to only the first filter using parentheses, otherwise the OR won't apply properly, . So if this filter is to be combined with others, ensure the filter intersects the resultset (assuming that filter should apply to all documents) :

```
fq=(-field:[* TO *]) OR (*:* AND -field:<val>)
```

Note this is equivalent to :

```
fq=-(field:[* TO *] AND field:<val>)
```

Which means you only need that part (as long as `<val>` is not null, ie. matches with a value different than 1 includes null/empty values)  :

```
fq=-field:<val>
```

Comment: My question is about using `NOT or NOT` in solr query. Also I believe `-field:*` is same as `-field:[* TO *]`

Comment: I have edited my post, the `val` is among set of values for ex `{1,2,3}`. I want to query `-field:1`.

Comment: I messed up with when saying you don't need the second filter, I edited my post as well. And I ensure you `-field:*` is not the same as `-field:[* TO *]`, only the latter guarantees to return _all_ documents having a null or empty value in that field, or no value at all (no field:value).

Comment: You probably need `*:*` in front of the first set before `OR` - as soon as you introduce the `OR`, the implicit set matched by `*:*` is no longer added to the query (at least that's how it was earlier), so the first set doesn't match any documents as currently written.

Comment: @MatsLindh I think it's correct but it concerns only the part after the first OR, (it was a few years ago, ~2016, though I can't test for now) : the implicit `*:*` set is always assumed for the first part of a filter (`field:value` => `*:* AND field:value`), but is required for the next ORed filter(s) if any. I will find some time to make tests and come back here to clarify things.

Comment: So I just tested on a solr 8.5.1 instance, my statement is correct as long as _the first negated filter is enclosed into parenthesis_ : `(-field:[* TO *]) OR (*:* AND -field:value)`.