# Why does my OR query return nothing but the left and right side of it return results on their own?

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm writing a Solr query that is trying to just check two fields for being empty, basically. The two individual queries for the fields both return results ...

```
NOT LongWords:*
```

and

```
NOT X_LongWords:*
```

But if I combine them with an OR they do not return anything ...

```
(NOT LongWords:*) OR (NOT X_LongWords:*)
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: The following should work as a fq : `(-LongWords:[* TO *]) OR (*:* AND -X_LongWords:[* TO *])`. Nb. `!A ∪ !B = !(A ∩ B)`, so you can write `-(LongWords:[* TO *] AND X_LongWords:[* TO *])`. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71765905/2529954) for more info.

Comment: The reason is that Solr prefixes the set encompassing all documents (`*:*`) in front of your query so negative queries work "out of the box", but when you have multiple clauses that does not happen, so you have to add the set explicitly to have something to subtract the matching documents in the negative set from.

Comment: Thank you both. That solved my issue. SO also showed this helpful related question that I wish I had found sooner. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28859224/294120